# Are my Salvia Blue dead? or will they bloom again?

Tags: plant-care

[image]My Salvia stem and leaves went from deep green to olive green and the flower from purple/blue to light brown. This is my first time planting this type of plant. I didn't do the best research and I believe they have died. They areally still standing and in tact, but looked slumped over, thin, and dried out. Should I take out or can I help them?

Also, I live in Texas. The plants receive 6+ hours of sun. I planted them (6) about 3-4 weeks ago.
I also planted some smaller ones in pots and those are doing great.

Comment: A photo would help.

Comment: Welcome! As Giacomo said, we could really use a picture to make the diagnosis. Also, where do you live? Are they in sun or shade? How old are they? Has the weather changed recently? Please give us as many details as possible. Just press "edit" under your question. It will open up and you can add anything you want. Thanks, and I hope you have fun here!

Comment: I bought them at home Depot and the tag read "Salvia Blue" it said drought and sun resistant. It has rained at least 1-2x a wk. I read they need well drained area. I'm sure they've been over watered  & not draining. I've used miracle gro all purpose soil and miracle gro sprayer feeder.